# How to use foreach to update value in Database iteratively?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am working for a database as below and trying to update all the role rows when click update button. How do I use the `foreach` method correctly for the `update` SQL commend if I want to update all 1 to 2? Do I need to push all the post value to an array then using `foreach` method. Is the following code correctly to set the SQL commend? Thanks!

```
foreach() {
  $sql = "UPDATE user_table set role = ? WHERE id = ?";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('ii', $role, $id);
  $result = $stmt->execute();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `foreach`. You can do it entirely in SQL:

```
UPDATE user_table SET role = 2 WHERE role = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to update 'role' column and change the value of '1' to '2'.

Best way to proceed would be to rely on SQL entirely.

Try This without any loops

```
$role_to_change = 1;
$new_role = 2;
$sql = "UPDATE user_table set role = ? WHERE role = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute([$role_to_change, $new_role]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also a few points about your code as provided:

- Prepare the statement once, outside the loop. Then, repeatedly execute it, binding new parameter values each time.
- Use transactions.  `BEGIN TRANSACTION` before you start updating, then `COMMIT` upon completion.  Or, `ROLLBACK` if anything goes wrong *(e.g. in a "try...catch" block)*.  This will make the operation **atomic** as seen by all other database users – they will see all the updates occurring at the same instant, or they will see that nothing happened at all. *(On many database systems, this also makes the operation considerably faster and more efficient.)*